# Weird error on typing a command + tab key (debian)

Tags: debian-lenny

I get a weird message on my shell when I try to type the command below and pressing the tab key

cd /home/

What i get is shown below:

cd /ho-sh: <( compgen -d -- '/ho' ): No such file or directory

I don't know why I get this message on my screen.

Did I break something on the server, that I can't be able to use the tab key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I  have found the problem. It was due to my login using the wrong shell. So modified my /etc/passwd file by using the command

chsh -s /bin/bash username

:)